# What does this "put nose in someone's life" mean?

Tags: phrases

"Why should I put my nose in his life" I read this in article of apathetic co-worker.

What exactly it mean?

Comment: The "standard" phrasing is *Why should I **poke** my nose **into** his life?* They might look like small differences, but your version would always be noticed as "odd". Here's the relevant definition for [***poke/stick one's nose into...***](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/poke-ones-nose-into)

Answer (score 1):

To *poke your nose into something*, means to interfere with something that doesn't concern you.

> [If someone pokes their nose into something or sticks their nose into something, they try to interfere with it even though it does not concern them.](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-poke-your-nose-into-something) -- Collins Dictionary
>
> [To involve oneself in an intrusive or nosy manner into something that is not one's business or responsibility.](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/poke+nose+into) -- The Free Dictionary

So "why should I put my nose in his life?" is asking "why should I involve myself in his life when it does not concern me?"

Comment: Note it can be either **"poke"** or **"stick"** one's nose in, but not **"put"**.